# iphone os 4 sdk landscape orientation problem

Tags: iphone, orientation, landscape

My application has a tab bar controller with a navigation controller in each of its tabs . The application is completely Landscape oriented. But when I try to run in iPhone OS 4, it is not changing to landscape at all. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try on other iphone OS like 3.1.3, is it the problem with iOS4 only?

Comment: yes. its an ios4 problem only.. I now re installed my old sdk and checked. Its working fine.